# A link inside a link?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I am making a rails app, and I have a class that is a link (its inside a  tag). I want `<%= User.find_by_id(p.user_id).username %>` to be a link to the user, so my questions are:

1) How do I make it a link to the user?

2) When I click on a link that I make, that is inside another link, it activates the outer link. How can I make the click respond the the inner link instead? (in the code under).

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="fg" href="#<%= p.id %>" data-toggle="modal">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="5px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= image_tag(p.thumbnail, class: "hoi") %>
                        </td>

                        <td id="tzt2" width="60%">

                            <div id="withJosefin">
                                <%= p.title %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="withLibre">
                                by <%= User.find_by_id(p.user_id).username %> <%= time_ago_in_words(p.created_at) %> ago
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a link using this syntax:

```
<% user = User.find_by_id(p.user_id) %>
<%= link_to user.username, user %>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
<%= link_to p.user.username, user_path(p.user) %>
```

By the way, why do you load the user manually? If your associations are set up correctly, you can just write:

```
<%= link_to p.user.username, p.user %>
```

I'm not sure I understood your second question. If you can explain it a bit more clearly I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @alessandro1997, the `<%= link_to p.user.username, p.user %>` worked perfectly :) I rewrote the second question, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: If you want to create nested hyperlinks, I don't think that's possible. I also can't imagine a scenario where that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cant nest hyperlinks.
You could either use some JavaScript to simulate the effect of nested hyper links, or a better solution is to reorganize your markup so that it is valid markup. i.e. your first  tag shouldnt contain divs etc.